# which command to use in SunOS which is equal to zgrep in linux

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to find a string in *.gz file and try the following;

```
   zipgrep user >filename>.gz 
     [<filename>.gz]
     End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
     a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
     latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
     the last disk(s) of this archive.
     zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of <filename>.gz or
      010414:22:59.serverlog.gz.zip, and cannot find <filename>.gz.ZIP, period.
      /usr/bin/zipgrep: test: argument expected

zgrep is not available;
 zgrep -h
      -bash: zgrep: command not found
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it have `zcat` and `grep`?

Comment: Actually, you would need `gzcat` and `grep`.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Thanks for the correction for SunOs, odd that the SunOS zcat man pages suggests they are the same command on that os.

Comment: I tried zcat also but it is giving me this error; <filename>.gz |grep -i user-user     
<filename.serverlog.gz.Z: No such file or directory

Comment: @BroSlow I suspect it depends on the version... see for example [the heirloom project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @user3216416 Have you tried Elliott Frisch's suggestion of using gzcat?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried zcat also but it is giving me this error; .gz |grep -i user-user

That indicates you're doing something like this:

```
zcat '<filename>.gz |grep -i user-user <filename.serverlog.gz.Z'
```

You want this:

```
zcat filename.gz | grep -i user-user
```